# PHPMySQL query database with string / array problems with results

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, search

I'm new at this so please be patient if I don't have the right phrases for everything. ;-)

I' trying to query a database. I have a string that can have 1-3 fixed values which comes from an imploded $_Post["array"] of a checkbox input form. Values are somthing like:

```
$string            // values (Berlin, New York, Rome) or (Berlin, Rome) ect.
```

Now I'm trying to query a database where each row(item) has a column(field) with 1-3 of the same values.

```
item1 (New York, Rome)
item2 (Berlin, New York, Rome)
item3 (Rome)
```

I've tried queries like these:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'destination' LIKE '%$string%'
or
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'destination' IN '$string'
```

While both theoretically work, they don't get me the results I want. Here is what I would like to have from the query:

> If $string has *all 3 values*, I want to display *all 3 items* (not only item2).
>
> If $string has *value(Rome)*, I want to display *item1*, *item2* and
>   *item3*.
>
> If the $string has the *value(New York, Berlin)* I want to display *item1*
>   and *item2*

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thx a lot
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys! Here is what I did in the end. Thx for your help

```
$query = "select * from table ";

$query .= "WHERE
            example1 like '$example1' 
            AND example2 like '%$example2%' AND (";
foreach($array as $Filtervalues)
{
  $query .= " example3 like '%".$Filtervalues."%' OR";

}   

$query = trim($query, " OR"); 
$query .= ")";

$query .= " ORDER BY
            name
            "; 
echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that your table column name is destination and $string is the post value from the form, you could try [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($string,  `destination` );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I got `table` with columns

```
ID     destination
1      New York, Rome
2      Berlin, New York, Rome
3      Rome
```

and some input from html form - array.
This works:

```
<?php
$cities=array("Rome", "New York", "Berlin"); // simulation of form input

foreach($cities as $value): // each city
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `destination` LIKE '%$value%'"); // find all match records for the city
  echo "<h3>For city \"$value\" I found in `table` these IDs</h3>";  
  while($value=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)): // fetch SELECT into rows
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value[0]); // prints IDs from DB corresponding with city in heading
    echo "</pre>";
  endwhile;  
endforeach;
?>
```